# How to properly set up a monorepo in TypeScript using workspaces to deploy AWS lambda functions with CDK?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to understand how to set up a monorepo using yarn workspaces and TypeScript. I want to deploy the "tasks" as lambda functions to AWS.

Here's a simple monorepo that I've created: https://github.com/chribben/monorepo-test

It has two workspaces, one called my-task and one called my-shared. The former has a dependency on the latter.

These are the steps I take to transpile and install the dependencies.

```
yarn build
cp tasks/my-task/package.json dist/tasks/my-task/
cp my-shared/package.json dist/my-shared/
cp package.json dist
yarn --cwd dist/tasks/my-task/ install
```

Which results in this structure:

```
- dist
  - my-shared
  - node_modules
  - tasks
    - my-task
```

The lambda function is created in CDK like so:

```
    const handler = new lambda.Function(this, "HelloMonorepo", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../dist/tasks/my-task"),
      handler: "index.hello",
    });
```

This will not include necessary dependencies in the deployment.
So my question is how to properly include the dependent artefacts (i.e. my-shared and node_modules) in the deployment?

Note that the idea is to have multiple lambdas, each with its own deployment artefact (containing only the code relevant for it) so I don't want to have one deployment artefact containing all the code and dependencies for all lambdas (i.e. the whole dist folder)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CDK will only zip and send to S3 bucket the code inside the directory your indicate in your `code` property when creating the Lambda function.

In your example, my-task only contains /src and package.json.

You should reference the whole directory and modify your lambda function to something like :

```
    const handler = new lambda.Function(this, "HelloMonorepo", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../dist"),
      handler: "/tasks/my-tasks/index.hello",
    });
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid, i.e. having a deployment artefact containing all the code for all the lambdas. I should clarify the question.

Comment: If you include your directory containing the node_modules in your code property, you'll have exactly that. Each deployed lambda will have its own modules, and it'll not be shared between lambdas. On the other side, if you'd like to share dependencies, you could use Lambda Layers (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Comment: try to bundle your code with esbuild or webpack and let cdk use the bundled file.
you can also use lambda.NodeFunction and it should bundle the files for you:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-nodejs.NodejsFunction.html